# changing dinamically class and id on vue components

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

i'm a bit new to vue, and maybe i'm trying to do something that is not doable.

i have this skeleton:

```
<div class="row"> <!--FIRST ROW-->
 <skills-list></skills-list>  
</div>
<div class="row"> <!--SECOND ROW-->
 <skills-list></skills-list>  
</div>
<div class="row"> <!--LAST ROW-->
 <skills-list></skills-list>  
</div>
```

now i have three row, each of them contain a vue custom component, this is my app:

```
Vue.component('skills-list', {
    template: `
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="text-center">
        <i :class="skills[0].class"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-container">
        <div class="progress" :id="skills[0].id"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    `,
    data: function(){
      return {
        skills : [
          {'class':'icon-html5-alt skills_icon','id':'#progress-html'},
          {'class':'icon-css3-alt skills_icon','id':'#progress-css'},
          {'class':'icon-javascript-alt','id':'#progress-js'}


        ]
      }
    }


  });

new Vue({
        el: '#cv_app',
    });
```

my custom component template has two dinamic value, the class and the id, that are listed in the skills array.
i want to fill those value for every template i insert in the html code, i mean: replace in some way :class="skills[0].class with :class="skills[i].class iterating over the skills array.
Hope i explain my self clear, is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? Inspect the rendered output. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/wPZPwY?editors=1010 or alternatively this. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/gXyXOz?editors=1010

Comment: you might want to look into https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props